# Unable to create toggle effect - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I'm following along in the tutorials with an AngularJS and am unable to create a toggle effect.

My console reads this error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'show' of undefined
    at new  (http://practice.dev/app.js:41:25) which points to this line of code: `$scope.menuState.show =  false;`

app.js

```
  app.controller('DeathrayMenuController',['$scope', function ($scope){
            $scope.menuState.show =  false;
            console.log($scope.menuState.show)

            $scope.toggleMenu=function(){
                $scope.menuState.show = !$scope.menuState.show;
            };

            $scope.stun=function(){
                console.log('stunned')
            };
            $scope.disintegrate=function(){
                console.log('disintegrated')
            };
            $scope.disintegrate=function(){
                console.log('Erased')
            };
        }]);
```

index.html

```
<div ng-controller='DeathrayMenuController'>
            <button ng-click='toggleMenu()'>Toggle Menu</button>
            <ul ng-show='menuState.show'>
                <li><button ng-click='stun()'>Stun</button></li>
                <li><button ng-click='disintegrate()'>Disintegrate</button></li>
                <li> <button ng-click='erase()'>Erase from history</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Before `$scope.menuState` just put `$scope.menuState = {}` You need to initialize menuState..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As PSL noted, `$scope.menuState` is not defined.

Before you add properties to an object, you must create the object.

Change your second line to read:

```
$scope.menuState = { show: false };
```

Answer (score 0):

To Create toggle effect in Html elements using AngularJS, we will use ngHide directive of AngularJS.

AngularJS ngHide directive is used to shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided to the ngHide attribute.

**Example**

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="toggleApp" ng-controller="toggleController">
<input type="button" value="Toggle Div" ng-click="ShowHide()" />
<br>
<br>
<div ng-hide="IsHidden">My DIV</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('toggleApp', [])
app.controller('toggleController', function ($scope) {
//hide the DIV by default.
$scope.IsHidden = true;
$scope.ShowHide = function () {
//If DIV is hidden it will be visible and vice versa.
$scope.IsHidden = $scope.IsHidden ? false : true; }
});
```

I have Taken reference from http://www.tutsway.com/create-toggle-effect-in-html-elements-using-angular-js.php